# Git to existing SVN

Tags: git, svn

I have tried all of the suggestions I can find on SO but nothing quite works. I want to periodically move an active Git repo over to an existing, but currently empty, SVN repo. Following the higher rated suggestions from SO the best I can do is  check out the Git repo into my SVN trunk but then I end up with a huge number of merge issues as I try to rebase (as per the suggestions on can find).

What do I need to do to periodically move my Git master branch into this SVN repo while preserving my Git history?

Comment: Don't search SO, but firstly read [manual git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client), *git svn* will give you some hint.

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is an okay solution. [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) is a much better solution in my experience. I suggest you start by looking at the [translation limitations](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#26) to see if any of those limitations will affect the ability to translate your repository.

From the rebasing issues you describe it sounds like you need to focus on your branch management strategy.

Answer (score 0):

As an option - put it into github: https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/